# How to lazy paginate a bootstrap table with slow data

Tags: django, bootstrap-table

We have a scientific database with a number of fields that are Django "cached properties".  These cached property fields are slow to retrieve.  Rendering a table (decorated with bootstrap-table) with around a thousand results is annoying, but doable.  However now that we're loading a lot more data into the database, rendering these tables ends up hitting the 90 second browser timeout.

We have explored various options to speed things up, but most methods do not support cached properties, which is a non-starter.  We're looking for a temporary solution short of taking the cached property speed issue (which is the root of the problem) head on.

Our current idea was to paginate.  However, it looks like it's impossible to do it without a major refactor in order to retain all of our current complex functionality.

We would like to retain this bootstrap functionality:

- Column switching (show/hide columns) between page loads
- Column sorting such that it takes *all* data (on or off the current page) into account

And we want to retain this complex Django functionality/implementation:

- Complex django templates that renders data on each row that spans multiple many-to-many table relationships using nested loops and custom tags that:

  - Filter records from M:M related table records that result from the limited way Django joins these tables and do not match search terms, when a related table field is used in the search.  (I can explain this in detail on request if this is confusing.)
  - Adjust the result count in javascript due to the above filtering
- Display of cached proerties

Maybe it's easier to try and solve the slow cached property issue...  Is there a way to tell Django to cache cached properties for a month or only re-cache them when new data is loaded?

Comment: A separate cache backend (redis/memcached) to cache the results of `cached_property` would indeed be needed, since `cached_property` is only cached on the lifetime of a model instance.

Comment: @BrianDestura Could you elaborate or link a good reference on that?

Comment: I was referring to an approach that uses django's [cache](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#basic-usage) framework that utilises [redis](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#redis) or [memcached](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#memcached). WIth that, you can store the expensive calculations done on those "cached properties". You can use the model instance's pk as a cache key and the calculated value as the cache value

Comment: Well, I successfully implemented `memcached`, but to my surprise, it is consistently 2-5 seconds *slower* than without it. So since the DB operations seemed to outperform the cache, I tried setting a DB cache table, but for some reason 2/3s of the values are not retained despite setting `timeout=None`. `memcached` with the same code, didn't have that issue... scratching my head. Maybe I should ask a new question?

Comment: Apparrently memcached doesn't use the default MAX_ENTRIES, which is why it didn't have an issue, but database caching does. Once I set a custom MAX_ENTRIES, database caching stored all the values. Further testing today shows that the performance improvement is effectively nil. There might on average be a marginal speedup. It's looking like time is evenly divided between data retrieval and transferring/rendering. And maybe I'm getting a second back from data retrieval, but that improvement is only seen when you average my test results.

Comment: Hmm the result being worse is weird, since the calculated values are stored which then should reduce any delays. Is the application and the cache backend (when you were using memcached) in the same server? Are you able to share some code sample?

Comment: At the end of the day yesterday, I tested it on very large real data and there was a significant performance improvement. My initial tests were on 2600 rows and apparently the improvement of 2-3 seconds wasn't consistent enough to overcome random rendering delays. That's my guess anyway. Either way, it's improved. Ultimately, it's overall too slow to serve a 150k row table, so I'm looking into server-side pagination and sorting in bootstrap table.

Comment: To provide more detail... Yesterday, I had timed the 2600 rows tests in the stopwatch app on my phone and I tapped lap for events in the log, the un-formatted table appearing, and the completion of the load. The completion of the data retrieval in the log was evident and the time with/without caching was too random to see the improvement, but the average was slightly improved.